# Get the last TikTok video using API V2 and html+javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, tiktok, tiktok-api

I am developing the website of an organization that uses TikTok to spread videos, and it needs to show the basic information of the last video uploaded to the tiktok channel of the organization (video title, date and image)

It has been difficult for me to move forward, but this is what I have:

- I registered the developer account on tiktok
- I created an app, (I have the app_id, client_key and client_secret)
- in the same app, I enabled "user.info.basic" and "video.list" (I put the app to be verified with tiktok)
- had to add login kit to use video list

I also haven't found a way to test HTTP GET to see the resulting JSON.
Im want to use it in conjunction with html and javascript.

references:
https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/display-api-get-started/
https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/tiktok-api-v2-video-list